# You cannot perform operation Remove on an object in state Existing

Tags: c#, smo

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with smo dll
and trying to remove a  file from database files with the following procedure

```
public string RemoveFile(string fileName,string databaseName)
{
   Server srv = new Server(servConn);
    Database database = srv.Databases[databaseName];
    if (database != null)
    {
        var file = LoadFiles(databaseName).Where(a => a.Name == fileName);

        if (!file.Any())
        {
            SqlServerDisconnect();
            return "File  Doesn't  Exist.kindly Enter Right File Name";
        }
        else
        {
            DataFile fileToRemove = file.FirstOrDefault();
            database.FileGroups[fileToRemove.Parent.Name].Files.Remove(fileToRemove);
            database.Alter();

            return "File  Removed Successfully";
        }
    }
}
```

I am not going to mention the code of servConn  parameter and  SqlServerDisconnect in order to abbreviate code that I have used in other places and I am sure that it works well.

When I remove a file  that I take it's name from one of existing files' logical names

```
RemoveFile("File1",MyDataBase")
```

I get the message: 
`You cannot perform operation Remove on an object in state Existing`.

How can I update the state of the file before removing it even though state field is read only and is my way in removing the file right?

Answer (score 0):

You are using SMO however; For alternative way, If you can execute the SQL to do these operations. I would suggest to simply use TSQLs to remove file like :

```
ALTER DATABASE SchoolDb2012  
REMOVE FILE schoolDataFile1;  
GO
```

You can find detailed information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-file-and-filegroup-options?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: ofcourse i know that i can use TSQl but i need to manage my database through smo

Answer (score 0):

i updated my procedure to drop  the file directly and not from it's file group
and the exception disappeared

```
public string RemoveFile(string fileName,string databaseName)
{
   Server srv = new Server(servConn);
    Database database = srv.Databases[databaseName];
    if (database != null)
    {
        var file = LoadFiles(databaseName).Where(a => a.Name == fileName);

        if (!file.Any())
        {
            SqlServerDisconnect();
            return "File  Doesn't  Exist.kindly Enter Right File Name";
        }
        else
        {
            DataFile fileToRemove = file.FirstOrDefault();
            fileToRemove.Drop();
            database.Alter();
            return "File  Removed Successfully";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetState change the SmoObject status 
e.g.

```
 var removeColumn = target.Columns.OfType<Column>().Where(x => !source.Columns.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();
 foreach (Column columItem in removeColumn)
        {
             //If you want remove this item just replace Remove to SetState  
            columItem.SetState(SqlSmoState.ToBeDropped);
            //If I use Remove will got You cannot perform operation Remove on an object in state Existing
            //target.Columns.Remove(columItem.Name);
        }
```